# How to paste into ansi-term (evil-mode)

Tags: spacemacs, evil, ansi-term

I want to copy some text from my browser and paste it into ansi-term. I am a vim user and I want to give spacemacs a try once again.

Naturally what I did was:

- Opening `ansi-term` by typing `SPC SPC ansi-term`.
- Switch to normal-state by pressing `ESC`.
- Switch to my browser, copy some text
- Switch back to emacs, press `p` which seems to be right (the text was pasted)

So I try some alternatives

- Press `enter`, and surprised since the `command` didn't executed
- Press `i` to switch to insert mode, and do it again. Yet still didn't work.
- Press `SPC SPC term-paste`, now it works

What I expect is, I can simply use evil binding to copy-pasting things in spacemacs and get it work.

Can anybody please show me what's wrong and how to do this correctly?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I can get it works by switching to `line mode`. So, after I start `ansi-term`, I need to press `Ctrl c Ctrl j`. Still looking for a better way if there is any.

**EDIT AGAIN:**
The official way to do this is `<S-Insert>` (`shift` + `insert`)

Comment: Is it bound to `S-insert` by any chance?

Comment: I see that on the docs. But what S exactly is? Capital S or space? I try both, S and space, and I can't get it work.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Ah, I see. `S-insert` is `shift + insert`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A command to paste into an `ansi-term` is bound to <kbd>S-insert</kbd> (that's <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>insert</kbd>) by default.

> runs the command term-paste (found in term-raw-map), which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘term.el’.
>
> It is bound to .
>
> (term-paste)
>
> Insert the last stretch of killed text at point.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of spacemacs (as of jan 2018), `SPC SPC` is replaced by `SPC :`.

So in order to get `term-paste` working, you have to do `SPC : term-paste` in `ansi-term`